# Find all numbers $ t$ so that the expansion of $1/t $ in base 10 has period 4

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all numbers $ t$ so that the expansion of $1/t $ in base $10$ has period $4$.

My try: I don't know the procedure to solve it.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from the smallest value of $1/t$, which is $1/t_m = 0.\overline{0001}$ . Any other qualifying $1/t$ must be a multiple of this, which means that any other qualifying $t$ must be a factor of $t_m$.

So let's find $t_m$. Clearly $10000\cdot 1/t_m =  1.\overline{0001} = 1+1/t_m$, so $10000=t_m+1$ and $t_m=9999$.

Then finding prime factors,  $9999 = 3^2\cdot 11\cdot 101$ and there are $3\cdot 2\cdot2 -2=10$ other factors of $9999$ to check whether they are period $4$: $\{3, 9,11,33, 99,101,303,909,1111,3333\}$ .

Comment: I m confused..What are the value of $t?$

Comment: $101,909,1111$ have period $4$.

Comment: so, $t=\{101,909,1111,9999\}$

Comment: @MatheMagic revision from $9=3^2$, sorry I missed that out.

Comment: @MatheMagic again they are factor pairs $(3,3333)$ and $(33,303)$ so it's easy to see what the decimals of the extra candidates are.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

So, $t$ must divide $10^4-1=9\cdot101\cdot11$

and must not divide $10^2-1,10-1$

Comment: i.e we have to find $t$ such that $10^4\equiv 1\mod t $

Comment: But how to deal with your 2nd line .Please explain.

Comment: @MatheMagic There aren't many divisors of $9 \cdot 101 \cdot 11$. Can you list them all?

Comment: $1, 3, 9 ,11, 33, 99, 101, 303 ,909 ,1111, 3333, 9999$